# "could not parse dogstatsd metric values: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "false": invalid syntax" error in flink application

Tags: apache-flink, datadog, statsd

For a flink application, I am publishing flink metrics using StatsdReporter on Datadog.
Getting errors in log:

1. .isBackPressured:false|g"': could not parse dogstatsd metric values: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "false": invalid syntax
2. KafkaSourceReader.KafkaConsumer.version:2.8.0|g"': could not parse dogstatsd metric values: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "2.8.0": invalid syntax
3. Source.KafkaSourceReader.KafkaConsumer.commit-id:ebb1d6e21cc92130|g"': could not parse dogstatsd metric values: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "ebb1d6e21cc92130": invalid syntax

and more suce errors. How to fix?.
for flink-version: 1.14.3

Sending metrics to datadog using flink StatsdReporter and datadog agent. Got parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

All metrics are of type `double` so you can't pass strings. Those bits of information need to be passed as tags. If possible, you should consider using the HTTP integration via [`DatadogHttpReporter`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#datadog), which will pass variables as tags by default for most things, and [make it easy to configure](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/flink/#metric-collection) for others.